# Multiple forms, one submit button in cakephp 3

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working in app with cakephp 3, in this app the admin users can register pays made for other users, what i am trying to do is allow the users to create multiple pays at once in the same view, one pay per user. what i have done is first create one form repeating the fields for each user.

The problem is when i click the submit button(i want only one), the data that i recive in my controller is always the data of the last fields. I don't know how to handle this in the rigth way.

Here is the code of mi view:

**addMulti.ctp**

```
<div class="pagos form col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-7">
<?= $this->Form->create(false) ?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user):
        echo '<br><strong>'.$user->full_name.'</strong>';
        echo $this->Form->checkbox('selected',['id'=>'select-'.$user->id,'onclick'=>'display_add_form('.$user->id.')']).'<br>';
        echo '<div style="display: none;" id= form-'.$user->id.'>';
        echo $this->Form->input('user_id', array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'value' => $user->id,
            'id'=>'user-'.$user->id
        ));
        echo $this->Form->input('mes', ['type' => 'month','selected'=>'0','id'=>'month-'.$user->id]);
        echo $this->Form->input('monto',['default' => $user->monto_paga,'id'=>'monto-'.$user->id]);
        echo $this->Form->input('año', ['type' => 'year', [
            'minYear' => date('Y')-2,
            'maxYear' => date('Y')+2
        ],'value'=> date('Y'),'id'=>'year-'.$user->id]);
        echo $this->Form->input('forma_pago', ['options'=>['Efectivo'=>'Efectivo','Transferencia'=>'Transferencia','Cheque'=>'Cheque'],'id'=>'pago-'.$user->id]);
        echo $this->Form->button('Cancelar',['type'=>'button','onclick'=>'hide_add_form('.$user->id.')','class'=>'btn btn-danger','id'=>'cancel-'.$user->id]);
        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Agregar Pagos'),['class'=>'btn btn-primary']);
    echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

```
<script>
function display_add_form(id){
    $("#form-"+ id).show('fast');
    $("#select-"+ id).hide();
}
function hide_add_form(id) {
    $("#form-"+ id).hide('fast');
    $("#select-"+ id).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue the answer from @Asif, it would be easier if you save each user separately.

```
...
echo $this->Form->input('users['.$user->id.'][mes]', ['type' => 'month','selected'=>'0','id'=>'month-'.$user->id]);
echo $this->Form->input('users['.$user->id.'][monto]',['default' => $user->monto_paga,'id'=>'monto-'.$user->id]);
...
```

In this way you could use an easy loop in the backend, like:

```
<?php
foreach($input['users'] as $userId => $user){
    echo $user['mes'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put the filed name as array so you can get all your form POST value in array cause you are posting multiple value under a single variable. I just give a simple html input field example below. Wish you know how to add in cakephp.

```
  <input type="text" name="year[]" id="your-id">
```